# Does running both Docker for Windows and Minikube require two physical network adapters?

Tags: docker, minikube, docker-for-windows

I am trying to learn both Docker and Kubernetes (on my Windows 10 machine).

I seem to be able to run Docker or Minikube, but not both.  It seems to come down to the networking.

They both want a hyper-v virtual switch.  And if I make one for Docker then Minikube can't use it or make a new one.  And if I make one for Minikube then I am in the same boat for docker.

For example, this command:

```
docker network create _transparent -d transparent
```

gives this error:

> Error response from daemon: hnsCall failed in Win32: An adapter was not found. (0x803b0006)

But if I then get rid of Minikube, docker works fine.

I tried to manually setup a separate virtual switch for each, but I get the following error:

> External Ethernet adapter 'Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection' is already bound to the Microsoft Virtual Switch protocol.

That leads me to believe that you can only have one virtual switch per physical network connection.

That leads to my final conclusion that, in order to run both Docker for Windows and Minikube at the same time, you must somehow have two active physical network connections.

**Is there another way to have both Docker for Windows and Minikube run at the same time?**

<sub><sup>Note: The reason I want the both to have network access at the same time is because I need Docker to be able to access my network as it builds container images, and I need Minikube to be able to access the network for general functionallity.</sup></sub>